# Why won't my buttons align?

Tags: html, css

For some reason my buttons won't align horizontally... I don't understand what's wrong. My buttons are all inline-block. The first image displays a website with the buttons, the second is a website without the buttons, just so that you may understand what I am talking about. Thanks a lot :).

My HTML:

```
<center>
<div id="menu"> 
    <form>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="About us" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Events" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Sign up" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Volunteer" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    </form>
    <form>
        <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Contact" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    </form>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
a:link{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
    }
    a:visited{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
    }
    input.MyButton {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 80px;
        height: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        color: rgba(250,250,250,0.5);
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
    }
    #menu{
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

[This is how it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4kEj.jpg)

[This is how it should appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGbRg.jpg)

Comment: Also, I am aware that all the buttons link to the same link. :P

Comment: Don't use forms and inputs as links, use anchor tags and style them accordingly. With your current approach, if JS is disabled, your navigation won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously, don't use input elements and JavaScript for what can be achieved using normal anchor tags.

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}
#menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <a href="about_us.html">About us</a>
  <a href="sign_up.html">Sign up</a>
  <a href="events.html">Events</a>
  <a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a>
  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Also, as Paulie_D states, the `<center>` tag has been deprecated. You can center elements using CSS as I have done in my example (div#menu).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [**Links are not buttons & vice versa**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/)

In your case, you are using a `form` for each `input`.

Just use one `form` wrapping them all.

```css
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}
input.MyButton {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
}
#menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <form>
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="About us" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Events" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Sign up" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Volunteer" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Contact" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
  </form>
</div>
```

By the way `<center>` has been deprecated for some time and should no longer be used. I'm surprised it's still coming up.

Comment: Interesting link you posted. In that article it states "If it navigates, it is a link. Use link markup with a valid hypertext reference"

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `form` tag is a block level element and it usually contains other block level elements so 1 `form` tag should be enough in this situation.

```
<form>
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="About us" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Events" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Sign up" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Volunteer" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="Contact" onclick="F:\practice website's\About us.html">
</form>
```

Also, consider not using `onclick` in your html as well as other inline javascript as it is considered bad practise overall, instead consider this example. Note this should be contained inside `<script></script>` tags.

`document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);`

Please also note, in your example you don't need any JS at all and what you're doing there is considered terribly bad practise. The way to approach that is as follow.

`<a href="path/other/file" class="myButton">Home</a>`

When making websites just use JavaScript when necessary as there are still people in this world that have JS disabled by default so you need to think about them also.

Comment: This is a perfect example of where JS is unnecessary.

Comment: yeah, definitely not necessary but may be useful for him in the future though.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your buttons are links rather than forms which you want to submit data from.  So change each form to a link

```
<a href="AboutUs.html">
    <input class="MyButton" type="button" value="About us" />
</a>
```

You could then consider removing the button as well and just style the `a` or put a `span` or `div` here.

Comment: Links can't contain inputs...they don't work correctly.

Comment: Good point :)  As per my text underneath they should consider removing the inputs altogether.

Comment: Nooooo. Don't do this.

Comment: @Penguin, have a look at Jack Zelig's answer.  This was more what I was trying to point out (use links instead of buttons) but I didn't give a very clear example (hence my downvotes).